# How did the authors of the (Credit Suisse) Global Wealth Databook calculate the Gini coefficient?

Tags: wealth, gini

how are you doing? I read the Global Wealth Reports from Credit Suisse and I wondered how the authors calculated the Gini coefficient. For example, on [page 84](https://www.credit-suisse.com/media/assets/corporate/docs/about-us/research/publications/credit-suisse-global-wealth-databook.pdf) of this databook from 2010, how did they calculate it? Can somebody show me how they did it? I would like to recalculate it in excel. Thank you very much.

*Example from the Databook 2010*
[image]

Comment: For the USA they probably used something like the [Survey of Consumer Finances](https://www.federalreserve.gov/econres/scfindex.htm) and similarly in other countries

Answer (score 1):

The GINI has fairly standardized calculation so you can just follow the standard formulas. The GINI is the ratio of the grey area on the plot below (taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) - which also mentions the formulas below) to the total area. Hence if you already have data where these areas are calculated you can simply compute GINI as:

$$GINI= \frac{A}{A+B}$$

If you have raw data then you can use formula:

$$GINI= \frac{\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1} |x_i-x_j| }{2n^2 \bar{x}}$$

where $x_i$ is the income of person $i$ (or if you are calculating wealth inequality wealth of person $i$). The formula above can be also rearranged in a different ways, so some textbooks/sources can express it in different way but the results will match.

Next the formula could be also expressed in terms of income distribution:

$$GINI= \frac{1}{2\mu} \int \int p(x_i) p(x_j) | x_i - x_j | dx_i dx_j $$

where $\mu$ is the mean of distribution of $x_i$.

You can find more on these in Sen, Amartya (1977), On Economic Inequality (2nd ed.). If you want something solely focused on GINI then Yitzhaki and Schechtman. The Gini methodology: A primer on a statistical methodology. Vol. 272. has an exhausting literature review on GINI.

[image]